# Azure - Change scaling set on loadbalancer and keep the same public IP

Tags: virtualization, azure, azure-networking

I have created on azure a resource group and within that resource group I have a load balancer with a public IP that includes a scaling set.

What I would like to do is to deploy another scaling set (new instances with new configuration) and point the old load balancer to this  new scaling set, and therefore maintaining the old public IP.

Is this possible to achieve ? Maybe another way that I would be able to change the scaling set and keep the same public IP (without downtime)?

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to deploy another scaling set (new
>   instances with new configuration) and point the old load balancer to
>   this new scaling set, and therefore maintaining the old public IP.

As far as I know, we **can't** change load balancer of azure vmss.

According to your description, I think you just want to keep this public IP address. In ARM module, we can associate this public IP address to another Load Balancer.

So, as a workaround, I think we can create VMSS with load balancer, then associate old public IP address to new load balancer.

> Maybe another way that I would be able to change the scaling set and
>   keep the same public IP (without downtime)?

If you VMSS' upgrade policy is set to **Manual**, the answer is **yes**, we can upgrade it without downtime.
we can change the URI that points to a new version of a custom image you built(properties > virtualMachineProfile > storageProfile > osDisk > image > uri).

We should upgrade VMSS instances one by one, here is a example about updates a windows vmss, after updating the model, **it does an update one virtual machine instance at a time**.

```
$rgname = "myrg"
$vmssname = "myvmss"
$newversion = "4.0.20160229"
$instanceid = "1"

# get the VMSS model
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname

# set the new version in the model data
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version = $newversion

# update the virtual machine scale set model
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

# now start updating instances
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname -InstanceId $instanceId
```

More information about upgrade Azure VMSS, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set).

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let us know if you need further assistance.  If it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)